# Microsoft Teams Python Botbuilder Proactive Messaging

Tags: python, azure, botframework, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

What was simple in Webex now seems fairly complicated in the Microsoft world.
What I specifically am looking to do is:

1. Create a bot in the Azure Bot Framework (Done)
2. Identify recipient ids using the botbuilder sdk using the recipient email
3. Use Botframework-Connector to individually identify these recipients, create new conversations, and proactively message them

This is what I have been using so far
https://pypi.org/project/botframework-connector/

```
from botbuilder.schema import *
from botframework.connector import ConnectorClient
from botframework.connector.auth import MicrosoftAppCredentials

APP_ID = 'azure_bot_app_id'
APP_PASSWORD = 'azure_bot_app_password'
SERVICE_URL = 'azure_bot_messaging_endpoint'
CHANNEL_ID = 'msteams'
BOT_ID = 'azure_bot_subscription_id'
RECIPIENT_ID = 'msteams_individual_user_id'

credentials = MicrosoftAppCredentials(APP_ID, APP_PASSWORD)
connector = ConnectorClient(credentials, base_url=SERVICE_URL)

conversation = connector.conversations.create_conversation(ConversationParameters(
            bot=ChannelAccount(id=BOT_ID),
            members=[ChannelAccount(id=RECIPIENT_ID)]))

connector.conversations.send_to_conversation(conversation.id, Activity(
            type=ActivityTypes.message,
            channel_id=CHANNEL_ID,
            recipient=ChannelAccount(id=RECIPIENT_ID),
            from_property=ChannelAccount(id=BOT_ID),
            text='Hello Person!'))
```

Is this even close to the right approach?

Comment: The approach you are following seems right to send [proactive Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet). Are you facing any issue?

Comment: yes, I seem to be missing the right parameters, to run this

Answer (score 2):

This was the easiest way I found to make it work.

```
from config import DefaultConfig

from botframework.connector.connector_client import ConnectorClient
from botframework.connector.models import ConversationParameters
from botframework.connector.auth.microsoft_app_credentials import MicrosoftAppCredentials
from botbuilder.core import  MessageFactory
from botbuilder.schema import ChannelAccount

CONFIG = DefaultConfig()

recipient_id = <<RECIPIENT_ID>>

to = ChannelAccount(id=recipient_id)
bot_channel = ChannelAccount(id='msteams')

MicrosoftAppCredentials.trust_service_url(CONFIG.SERVICE_URL)
credentials = MicrosoftAppCredentials(CONFIG.APP_ID, CONFIG.APP_PASSWORD)
conn_client = ConnectorClient(credentials, CONFIG.SERVICE_URL)

message_activity = MessageFactory.text(f"Personal message from the Bot!");
 
conversation_params = ConversationParameters(members=[to], channel_data={ 'tenant': { 'id': CONFIG.TENANT_ID } })

conversation = conn_client.conversations.create_conversation(conversation_params)

conn_client.conversations.send_to_conversation(conversation.id, message_activity)
```

It is easy to infer all the uppercase variables.

The `<<RECIPIENT_ID>>` is the MS Teams ID of the user you want to send the message.

Hope this helps.

MSFT does not provide good examples in Python.

Comment: I'm getting "Invalid user identity in provided tenant". What's the RECIPIENT_ID in the provided example? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

With a cursory glance it looks ok (I don't work in Python so can't actually run the example). One thing that *does* look missing in the TrustServiceUrl call. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=python#avoiding-401-unauthorized-errors) for details.

Comment: I did not see the TrustServiceUrl in the latest version. Also Hilton, do you know how to find the Service Url? I am using Azure, azurewebsites.net, and having trouble connecting to or finding the service_url.

Comment: I'm pretty sure TrustServiceUrl  is still required. ServiceUrl is unique to the user, so it's part of what you get when the user converses with (or installs for the first time) your bot. It's where you would have gotten RECIPIENT_ID from, basically